# How to set a particular byte in a file to 0 or 1?

Tags: c

I have a `char*` to where I want to set the byte, from malloc. How do I set it to 1 or 0, for example?

Comment: "I have a `char*` to where I want to set the byte" - that is (usually) not how files work. How did you get this pointer?

Comment: @user2357112 You're right. I got it from malloc.

Comment: Setting the value of the object a pointer points to in memory is step 1. The second is to save the value to the file. Which step are you stuck at?

Comment: Ummm, your question title asks about addressing and modifying a byte in a file.  Your actual question asks about how to dereference a pointer and modify the resulting _rvalue_.

Comment: @RSahu Well I just run memcpy after right?

Comment: @User, `memcpy` can't be used to write to a file. It seems like you need to step back a bit and learn about file IO first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign to your dereferenced pointer:

```
//This will (obviously) set it to 1
*your_pointer = 1;

//This will set it to 0
*your_pointer = 0;
```